# Jquery animate position is not working with margin-top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idinob/7/edit)** which has a div with labels

And I want to scroll to a specific label.

however it is working correctly only if `margin-top` is `0`.

HOwever If I test it with `margin-top:100px` it is not accurate... **http://jsbin.com/idinob/8/edit**

why is that ?

The animate command is :

```
$('.d').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".s210").position().top
 }, 200);
});
```

And I did use `position` and not `offset` because im talking a about a span which is **inside** the div. so we are talking about position and not offset.

it seems that `$(".s210").position().top` is affected by the margin-top.

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the position property to relative:

```
span { position: relative }
```

Comment: does it only work with relative ? I did tried it before and it did work. but in documentation it doesnt say anything

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, the position should be set to relative, There are several duplicate questions with detailed answers on SO about this issue.

Comment: well , I couldn't find any related question. and I'll be glad to mark this question as duplicate. Thanks.